# I can't install any extensions on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I tried a lot of methods to install, but the following log does not install.
I'm having a problem with other extensions not being installed. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Maybe, you need to run vscode as admin.

Comment: While installation it is searching for the directory which is unable to locate and it is showing you the error and saying that make a directory  with given path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see the error there is a given paths, these are added into *PATH* but actually not exist in you system.
Remove them or create them.